# The right way to send cqlsh command via ssh using PYTHON

Tags: python, ssh, cqlsh

I tried with PYTHON to send cqlsh command via ssh and keep getting errors like

1. no viable alternative at input ':'
2. dsecqlsh.py not valid port

...

and I searched over internet including stack overflow, none gives the answer.

```
def sshRemoteCmd(user,host,cmd):
    import subprocess
    import re
    x = subprocess.Popen("ssh {user}@{host} {cmd}".format(user=user, host=host, cmd=cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    result=''

    if not x:
        result = 'error'
    else:
        for item in x:
            result += item.decode('ascii')
    return result

cmd = f'''cqlsh -e "select * from MYTABLE where userid='12345';"'''
print(cmd)
result = sshRemoteCmd('root','hosts', cmd)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the all the tricks I tried, here the right answer

1. add localhosts and port number in the cqlsh cmd like

```
cqlsh localhosts 9042
```

2. add double quote to wrap the whole command
3. double escape the quote with \"

here's the final right code

```
def sshRemoteCmd(user,host,cmd):
    import subprocess
    import re
    x = subprocess.Popen("ssh {user}@{host} {cmd}".format(user=user, host=host, cmd=cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    result=''

    if not x:
        result = 'error'
    else:
        for item in x:
            result += item.decode('ascii')
    return result

cmd = f'''"cqlsh localhost 9042 -e \\"select * from MYTABLE where userid='1234';\\""'''
print(cmd)
result = sshRemoteCmd('root','hosts', cmd)
print(result)
```